# Контроллер asp net core не может распарсить post запрос

Tags: json, asp.net-core

Привет, у меня есть контроллер с методом:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route(FirstStepFilledRoute)]
    public IActionResult OnFirstStepFilled(
        PdoResultViewModel pdoResultViewModel,
        int id)
    {}
```

И форма, которая этот контроллер дергает:

```
@model WebApp.Models.PdoResultViewModel
<form asp-route="@Model.Route" method="post">
@for(int i = 0; i < Model.PdoQuestionSetViewModels.Length; i++){
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            @Model.PdoQuestionSetViewModels[i].Value
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            @for(int j = 0; j < Model.PdoQuestionSetViewModels[i].PdoQuestionAnswerViewModels.Length; j++){

                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>
                        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.PdoQuestionSetViewModels[i].PdoQuestionAnswerViewModels[j].Id)
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.PdoQuestionSetViewModels[i].PdoQuestionAnswerViewModels[j].IsChecked)

                        @(j+1).
                        @Model.PdoQuestionSetViewModels[i].PdoQuestionAnswerViewModels[j].Value
                    </label>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
}
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Далее" />
</form>
```

Модель:

```
public sealed class PdoResultViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public PdoQuestionSetViewModel[] PdoQuestionSetViewModels { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string Route { get; set; }
}

public sealed class PdoQuestionSetViewModel
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public PdoQuestionAnswerViewModel[] PdoQuestionAnswerViewModels { get; set; }
}

public sealed class PdoQuestionAnswerViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
}
```

При сабмите формы, я удачно попадаю в свой метод контроллера. Но часть данных не не приходит: pdoResultViewModel.PdoQuestionSetViewModels всегда null.
Я точно знаю, что данные пересылаются
Request.Form. содержит в себе необходимое количество заполненных  KeyValuePair.

Примерно следующее показывает консоль firefox'a:

```
...
PdoQuestionSetViewModels[0].PdoQuestionAnswerViewModels[0].Id:"15728"
PdoQuestionSetViewModels[0].PdoQuestionAnswerViewModels[0].IsChecked:"false"
...
```

Что я мог сделать неправильно? Почему контроллер не может распарсить сложную модель?

Answer (score 0):

Не дождавшись ответа переписал на более легкую вью-модель: теперь с формы в контроллер отправляю список {id: number, isChecked: bool}, а всё остальное во view-bag.

А вообще такое ощущение, что либо форма строит json в неправильном формате, либо нужна была какая-то магия с аттрибутами, либо наличие в модели конструктора или какого-то метода сбивает рефлексию с толку.